# Pandas calculate features based on different time windows

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have the following data frame for example:

```
TXN_ID                 TXN_DATE      TXN_TYPE
8C083F30C0674A72    01/01/2013 00:00    A
B610D7D4E2D14513    01/01/2013 00:00    B
698C5DD423AC42D6    02/01/2013 00:00    C
37E2B21583F949CA    12/01/2013 00:00    A
9FE25A547F964E93    13/01/2013 00:00    B
F6C14D987D584E53    14/01/2013 00:00    A
```

For each row I want to add 3 features - count distinct TXN_TYPE in the same day, in the past 3 days & in the past week.
so the dataframe would look like:

```
TXN_ID                TXN_DATE      TXN_TYPE Distinct_Type_1Day   Distinct_Type_3Day    Distinct_Type_7Day
8C083F30C0674A72    01/01/2013 00:00    A           2                  2                 2
B610D7D4E2D14513    01/01/2013 00:00    B           2                  2                 2
698C5DD423AC42D6    02/01/2013 00:00    C           1                  3                 3
37E2B21583F949CA    12/01/2013 00:00    A           1                  1                 1
9FE25A547F964E93    13/01/2013 00:00    B           1                  2                 2
F6C14D987D584E53    14/01/2013 00:00    A           1                  2                 2
```

What would the best & efficient way to do so?

Comment: What is the reference time from which 1, 3 and 7 days is to be measured? Do you want to do this for every record's TXN_DATE  in the frame ?

Comment: Yes for every record look at the TXN_DATE and 1day refers to all transactions from the same date, 3 days from past 3 days etc. There is only one time stamp per day at 00:00 'dd/mm/YYYY 00:00'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get the job done, but I use `apply` which I don't like.

```
def comp_dates(x):
    d = 'TXN_DATE'
    date = x[d]
    d1 = date - pd.offsets.Day(1)
    d3 = date - pd.offsets.Day(3)
    d7 = date - pd.offsets.Day(7)
    cond0 = df[d] <= date
    cond1 = df[d] > d1
    cond3 = df[d] > d3
    cond7 = df[d] > d7
    s = pd.Series([
            len(df[cond0 & cond1].TXN_TYPE.unique()),
            len(df[cond0 & cond3].TXN_TYPE.unique()),
            len(df[cond0 & cond7].TXN_TYPE.unique()),
        ], ['Distinct_Type_1Day', 'Distinct_Type_3Day', 'Distinct_Type_7Day'])
    return s

pd.concat([df, df.apply(comp_dates, axis=1)], axis=1)
```

[image]

---

#### Setup

I used this code to create the dataframe

```
text = """TXN_ID                 TXN_DATE      TXN_TYPE
8C083F30C0674A72    01/01/2013 00:00    A
B610D7D4E2D14513    01/01/2013 00:00    B
698C5DD423AC42D6    01/02/2013 00:00    C
37E2B21583F949CA    01/12/2013 00:00    A
9FE25A547F964E93    01/13/2013 00:00    B
F6C14D987D584E53    01/14/2013 00:00    A"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text), delimiter='\s{2,}', parse_dates=[1], engine='python')
```

Comment: Thanks. I get a TypeError:    TypeError: ("unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Day' and 'str'", u'occurred at index 0')

Comment: @Menkes I updated my post to show how I produced the test dataframe.  The problem is because your date column is a string.  You need to make it a date column.  I did it by telling `pd.read_csv` that column 1 should be parsed as a date.  You can also do `df.TXN_DATE = pd.to_datetime(df.TXN_DATE)`

Comment: @Menkes Also, this a good case in point to demonstrate the usefulness of provided your own code that produces the data you are working with.  When you copy and paste text, data types will get mixed up.

Comment: thanks a lot it works! Let's say I have another column now that is called STOCK_ID - and I want to count the distinct types for the date windows per specific stock_id - so the distinct value will be 2 only if per the specific stock_id in the time window of 1 day there were 2 transaction types - do I just add another condition that it equals the STOCK_ID?